# ASR for a SQL Server cluster active/active configuration

Tags: sql-server, azure, disaster-recovery

I have an application running on a SQL Server cluster with active/active configuration setup on-premises. I have some knowledge as to how to replicate a SQL Server cluster that is on-premises with SIOS data keeper cluster.

But, what I am interested is if it is possible to replicate the entire SQL cluster with Azure Site Recovery to Azure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is, but bear in mind that you would also need a working Domain Controller in Azure (most likely) for your cluster to function properly. Also, I believe, that just extending AlwaysOn to Azure in the way to go.

Reference: http://www.azurefieldnotes.com/2017/02/01/overview-of-asr-for-multi-tier-applications-using-sql-alwayson/